# .NET local variable optimization

Tags: c#, .net, optimization, decimal, jit

I was reading through the .NET sources when I found this:

```
// Constructs a Decimal from an integer value.
//
public Decimal(int value) {
    //  JIT today can't inline methods that contains "starg" opcode.
    //  For more details, see DevDiv Bugs 81184: x86 JIT CQ:
    //  Removing the inline striction of "starg".
    int value_copy = value;  
    if (value_copy >= 0) {
        flags = 0;
    }
    else {
        flags = SignMask;
        value_copy = -value_copy;
    }
    lo = value_copy;
    mid = 0;
    hi = 0;
}
```

As you can see, the constructor of the Decimal structure copies the method argument to a local variable rather than using it directly. I was wondering what the comment means and how it relates to performance & optimization?

My guess is that once you want to modify the existing argument, method can be no longer inlined?

http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/decimal.cs#f9a4da9d6e110054#references

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> *My guess is that once you <strike>want to</strike> modify the existing argument, method can be no longer inlined?*

**Short answer:** Your guess is correct (if that source code comment is still true today).

> ```
> //  JIT today can't inline methods that contains "starg" opcode.
> ```

**"The JIT"** is that part of the .NET runtime that translates [intermediate language (IL) (i.e. .NET "bytecode")](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Intermediate_Language) to your computer's assembly language. Only then can code be executed by your computer. The JIT performs this translation method-by-method, and only when actually needed: Whenever a method is first invoked, it is first compiled down to actual assembly language, "just-in-time" (JIT).

The C# compiler does not generate assembly language for your computer's architecture straight away; instead, it generates [intermediate language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intermediate_language), which is some kind of assembly language for an abstract stack machine (which was defined in the [ECMA 334 international standard](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-335.htm)).

For example, assignments to a parameter (in your example: `value`) would get translated by the C# compiler to an IL instruction called **`starg`** ("store to argument").

The comment basically says that if the method contained such an assignment (`value = …`), then the JIT would currently not be able to "inline" it. **["Inlining a method"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inline_expansion)** means that instead of generating call instructions to a method (i.e. branch commands to a different code location), the JIT would instead insert the method's whole body in the place where it is called. This is usually done to optimize execution speed, because no branch/jump is necessary, and additionally I assume that no new stack frame must be set up, too.

By assigning to a local variable instead (`value_copy = …`), this limitation of the JIT is circumvented, because assignments to local variables cause a different IL instruction to be generated: `stloc` ("store to local variable").

**See also:**

- [Andrey Akinshin: "A story about JIT-x86 inlining and starg"](http://aakinshin.net/blog/post/inlining-and-starg/) (blog post)

Comment: so basically your answer to his question is yes. I would have started with that and than add the explanation.

Comment: @Clueless: Thanks for your suggestion! I've added a TL;DR answer. I have that annoying tendency to give long-winded answers that I can't seem to get rid of. :)